# Load a generic script with a custom UID

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to give users a snippet to put on their own sites which loads a generic javascript file with a unique ID for that user. This is so the content which loads up is dependant on which user id is associated with it.

My best guess so far is something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var UID = '';

    (function() {
        var url = www.test.com/embed.js';
    })();
</script>
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view this content</noscript>
<a href="http://www.test.com" class="link">content powered by <span class="logo">Test</span></a>
```

I havent had a lot of luck with this code. Can anyone explain how I should be approaching this please?

Comment: What is the purpose of the unique ID for each user?

Comment: To show different content loaded in by AJAX

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way that google does it.  Let me know if you need help applying it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

Ref. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to append `<script>` tag to the DOM.
2. You should put your entire script inside a single scope (function)

   ```
   (function(window, uid) {
       var document = window.document;

       // create your <script> element
       var e = document.createElement("script");
       e.src = "//my.website.com/my-script.js?user-id=" + window.encodeURIComponent(uid);

       // insert it before the very first <script> element already in DOM
       var s = document.body.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
       s.parentNode.insertBefore(e, s);
   })(window, "some-user-id");
   ```